# How can I wake Arduino Pro Mini(Sleep mode) with DS1302?

Tags: arduino

I have Arduino Pro Mini and DS1302 Module.

And I setted arduino going to sleep mode.

How can I wake arduino with DS1302?

First of all, Is that a possible?
(use interrupt code?)

Comment: http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts

Answer (score 1):

The DS1302 does not have any alarm capability, therefore it can not be used to wake up your Arduino.

You would have to switch to an DS3231 for example, which has two programmable alarms. Those alarms will pull a pin on the DS3231 low, which you can use as an interrupt to wake up your Arduino.